# How to call async methods of one class into another class in c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

i have an Interface , it has a method prototype:

```
public interface IDataReceiver
{
  Task<HttpResponseMessage> ReceiveAsync(string id, HttpRequestMessage request);

}
```

i have an abstract class inheriting the interface

```
public abstract class DataReceiver :IDataReceiver
    {

        protected DataReceiver()
        {
        }
         public abstract Task<HttpResponseMessage> ReceiveAsync(string id, HttpRequestMessage request);
         protected virtual async Task<NameValueCollection> ReadAsFormDataAsync(HttpRequestMessage request)

    {
           //code to read the html request body
    }

}
```

i have another class inheriting **DataReceiver**

```
 public  class Reciever1 :DataReceiver
    {
        internal const string TokenParameter = "token";

        public override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> ReceiveAsync(string id, HttpRequestMessage request)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(id);
            }

             // Read the request entity body
             NameValueCollection data = await ReadAsFormDataAsync(request);
             string token = data[TokenParameter];
             HttpResponseMessage tstmsg = request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "Success"+token);
             return tstmsg;
}
}
```

I have controller class

```
 public class TestController : ApiController
    {
        [HttpPost]

        public  Task<HttpResponseMessage> ProcessData(string name)
        {
          retrun   ProcessWebhook(name);
        }

       private async Task<HttpResponseMessage> ProcessWebhook(string RecieverName)
        {
            //how to call the ReceiveAsync method of Reciever1  class

            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "Success" +" "+ RecieverName);

          }
}
```

I am trying to call **ReceiveAsync** method of **Reciever1**  class in **ProcessWebhook** method of **TestController** class   however not able to do that.i tried using **classname.methodname** way but its not showing the method.

any idea  on this please?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In TestController you need to have an **instance** of `Reciever1`. Create it using `new` keyword: `var receiver = new Reciever1();` Or resolve it from IoC container if you are using DependencyInjection.

To call method using it class name like `classname.methodname` the method MUST be marked as `static`.